# can't upload to s3 using axios in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

this is my code in nodejs:
this is my file from console.log:

```
file  {
  filename: 'Aaaasd.jpg',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
}
```

S3 config:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
      accessKeyId: ---,
      secretAccessKey: ---,
      region: 'us-east-2',
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
    });
```

and this is how i get a signed Url:

```
const s3Params = {
          Bucket: 's3BucketName',
          Key: file.filename,
          Expires: 60,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          ContentType: file.mimetype,
        };

    const signedRequest = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
```

and finally my put request:

```
const options = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': file.mimetype,
            'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
          },
        };
        const response = await axios.put(signedRequest, file, options);
```

basically i'm following a tutorial and i just don't get why my code don't work, this is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123:user/asd"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::zxc-asd"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my cors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

i'm not really sure why it seems hard to trace the cause why i can't upload and I'm getting 403 response, help?

Comment: whats the error, signature mismatch ?

Comment: the error is Access denied

Answer (score 0):

The policy is almost correct except that the `PutObject` permission requires the resource to be the object, not the bucket itself, there you can specify the resource as `"arn:aws:s3:::zxc-asd/*"` to target all the objects.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::zxc-asd"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::zxc-asd/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps